# how to add select2 jQuery to lookup in sharepoint using add web part(script editor)

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, jquery-select2

i have a SharePoint page and in that page i have a list with a lookup column.

i've tried to enet a script editor in the same page of the lookup with the following code but didn't work :

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
```

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $("jsgrid_combobox").select2();
               });
              </script>
```

i want to use select2() for that lookup. how can i do that using a script editor web part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include certain `select2` which you get easily from [GitHub](https://select2.github.io/)

Most Importantly, use of `$("jsgrid_combobox")` is inappropriate here, the selector should be either ***a tag, a class or an id***

`$("select").select2();` selects all selection boxes.

`$(".myClass").select2();` selects all elements with a class(myClass)

`$("#myId").select2();` selects an element with id(myId)

Comment: the selection is a lookup, and the previous id shown is the lookup id

Comment: As an aside, I prefer the ".myClass" method. Using the 1st option would mean all select's, even if you may not want all of them. The 3rd option means you would have to add many more lines of code if you have many select2 selection boxes in your form. Using the ".myClass" option allows more flexibility.